# how to pass data to Angular ng-bootstrap modal for binding

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

Scenario:

- ChildComponent - having a lot ngModel binding elements.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="TryToPassDataModel.name">;
```

- ParentComponent -

```
btn.onClick = function() {
  this.bsModalRef =
    this.modalService.open(ChildComponent, TryToPassDataModel);
}
```

This works in ngx-bootstrap, but how to implement this in nb-bootstrap? (it looks like such a simple idea)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like you're not using the API properly. The plugin expects the params to be passed as @Input(). Something like this would work :

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
```

Make sure you add a @Input for your model in ModalContent component!

See the doc for more info : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: This approach has a major problem: lifecycle hooks like `ngOnInit` are called before the variables are binded to the component.

Comment: To follow the changes on Input parametters, you should be using the lifecycle hook OnChanges : https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges. I haven't worked with angular in a while, but I think NgAfterViewInit will also work as you expect. Basicly ngOnInit is called when the component is constructed so the params don't have time to be propagated.

Comment: Sure :) In addition though, this pattern introduces another problem of change detection. I filed [an issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2645) at ng-bootstrap's GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

In **Angular 8** using **ng-bootstrap** Modal to pass data from parent component to modal

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ng-bootstrap-modals-tutorial-pass-data-from-parent-and-get-back-from-modals/)**

[image]

```
openModal() {
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MyBootstrapModalComponent,
  {
    scrollable: true,
    windowClass: 'myCustomModalClass',
    // keyboard: false,
    // backdrop: 'static'
  });

let data = {
  prop1: 'Some Data',
  prop2: 'From Parent Component',
  prop3: 'This Can be anything'
}

modalRef.componentInstance.fromParent = data;
modalRef.result.then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
}, (reason) => {
});
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you require the data to be available in the component when it is created.  Throw `console.log(this.fromParent)` in `ngOnInit() {}` in the modal and it will appear to work.  Simulate a delay with `setTimeout(() => {modalRef.componentInstance.fromParent = data}, 5000);` on the parent and now you'll get undefined when opening the component.