# How to pass data to ng-bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to open model from parent component. So, I got the dummy dialog opened from parent component taking help from : [how to pass data to Angular ng-bootstrap modal for binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698665/how-to-pass-data-to-angular-ng-bootstrap-modal-for-binding). On Dialog instead of dummy text , I have input box to display the infomration from parent component and at the same time user can edit this information and require this change to send back to Parent information. I try to do something like Angular Material MAT_DIALOG has using tokeninjection but I am not fully following it.

```
 import { Component, OnInit, InjectionToken, Injector, OnDestroy, 
  TemplateRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
  import {NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

         export interface CancelDialogData {
            name: string; // this can be any string;
            Comments: string;
         }
        export declare const CUSTOM_DIALOG_DATA: InjectionToken<any>;

          @Component({
           selector: 'app-reject-dialog',
        templateUrl: './reject-dialog.component.html',
           styleUrls: ['./reject-dialog.component.css']
           })
           export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit {

         constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,  
       @Inject(CUSTOM_DIALOG_DATA) public data: CancelDialogData) { }

          ngOnInit() {
                 }

              onCancelClick(): void {
                this.activeModal.close();
            }

                }
```

From parent Component:

```
     const dialogRef = this.modal.open(CancelDialogComponent, data: 
     {name: '', approverComments: ''});
```

when I am trying to pass this data , i have compiler error that data is not a NgbModalOptions.
        I really don't understand the InjectionToken here, it just appear more cleaner than @Input/ @output. Please assist how to achieve it like Active material Dialog.

Answer (score 9):

the docs use:

```
open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }
```

See that if we use the button "OK" we received in "re" the value, another case (if "cross" button or outside the modal, we received the "value" in "dismiss"

**Updated** How received a response

If we want received some value from our modal, we use the close function to send the value. e.g. our .html of modal is like

```
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
        <!--in function dismiss return a string-->
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" 
(click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Hello, <input [(ngModel)]="name">!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <!--but, in function close we return the "name" variable-->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close(name)">Aceptar</button>
    </div>
```

When we make the "open" and received a Modal reference

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent)
modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
modalRef.result.then(res=>{
  console.log("CloseButton", res)
},dismiss=>{
  console.log("Cross Button",dismiss)
})
```

See the example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjvkpn?file=app/modal-component.ts)

Comment: It worked. Thank you But let's say now i have edited the name value so, on close how to read this field-name changed value from my own defined function ? let say in dialog box: 
     <button  type="button"class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" (click) 
        ="activeModal.dismiss(name)">Submit</button>,then on parent component , i get the changed name value in reason: (reason) => {
             console.log(reason); }); but instead of using in-built dismiss function, I want to call different function in dialog, let say: onSubmit(name), how this one will fire back to parent

Comment: Until I know, you only has two options in a ngdModal, The modal it's closed using "close" function or using "dismiss" function. See my updated answer